# Inheritting from custom JPanel using NetBeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

`ContainerPanel` is a custom `JPanel` class using a `BorderLayout`. The SOUTH contains a `JPanel` with a button. I want the `CENTER` to be an instance of another custom `JPanel`, say `AbstractPanel`, which provides an abstract method which will be called when the button is clicked. I also want to set this `JPanel` programmatically (at run-time). So far, I can do all of this as you can see in the following code (some of which is generated by the NetBeans GUI Builder):

```
package jpaneldemo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class ContainerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public ContainerPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public ContainerPanel(AbstractPanel abPanel) {
        initComponents();

        this.abPanel = abPanel;
        this.add(this.abPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        okButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        okButton.setText("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);

        add(buttonPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        this.abPanel.abstractMethod();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel buttonPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton okButton;
    // End of variables declaration

    private AbstractPanel abPanel = null;
```

}

I also created the `AbstractPanel` class:

```
package jpaneldemo;

public abstract class AbstractPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public AbstractPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    protected abstract void abstractMethod();

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Now I want to create subclasses of this `AbstractPanel` class which I can edit in the NetBeans GUI. Typically, I right-click on a package name in the Projects window and then navigate to "New -> JPanel..." to create a custom `JPanel`. How do I get `AbstractPanel` to appear in the "New" menu so that I can edit the new class with the NetBeansGUI Builder? Or is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: +1 to the question, though hadn't tried my hands on NETBEANS as yet, just know a few things, never did any programming on that, though the question sounds a bit interesting though :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your intention is to provide a "template" component that can then be added to the palette and included in other containers, then yes you can.

Have a read through [FaqFormCustomContainerBean](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormCustomContainerBean)

The basic idea (apart from creating a `BeanDescriptor` is you will need to provide a "content" panel of some kind, where additional content can be added at design time.

Now, if you're interested in providing a custom template, that's something I've not done before.

You could try reading through http://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/customize-java-template.html.  It may be a little out of date, but might help you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll take a look. Part of my problem here is that I don't have a formal design. I'm just creating it all in my head. For the most part, it works; occassionally I hit some snags, though.

Comment: After thinking more about the design for my project, I've revamped my question. Hopefully what I want to do is a little more clear.

Comment: Given your update, I don't think it can be done, because the Form Editor will want to instantiate the component, which it can't because it's abstract

Comment: Hmm...sounds like I'll have to create the subclasses by hand, then. That's no problem. I started coding Java Swing in a text editor.

Comment: FWIW, I'll let this question sit for another day or so to see if anyone else has input. If not, I'll definitely accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm interested in seeing if any one has any more suggestions, cause I'd love to be able to do this to.  If the answer is useful, an up-vote is fine, but if it doesn't answer the question fully, then I don't expect an accept ;)

Comment: Already up-voted. I'll be glad to wait and see if anyone has an answer.